# Linq issues for a complex request

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a list of users and each users have list of hashtags.

In my app I provide a way on searching results by hashtags.

In my api I split the search string to get each hashtags separately and what I try to have is:

The user entity, the number of hashtags in common and the hashtags related.

For example:

My classes are as below:

```
    public class UserDto
    {
        public List<HashtagDto> Hashtags { get; set; }

    }

    public class HashtagDto
    {
        string name { get; set; }

    }

    public class UserHashtagSearchResultDto
    {
        public UserDto UserFk { get; set; }

        public int CountResults { get; set; }

        public List<HashtagDto> HashtagsFk { get; set; }
    }
```

My query:

```
if (searchText.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return null;

        var splits = searchText.Split(new string[] { " " }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        
        List<string> hashes = HashtagHelper.ToHashkeys(splits);

        if (hashes != null && hashes.Count() > 0)
        {
            User.GetUsers().Include(h => h.Hashtags).Where(s => hashes.Contains(....).Select((hs) =>
             {
                 return new UserHashtagSearchResultDto
                 {

                 }
            });
        }
```

Input will be: running swimming

Output will be:

List

Example:

Result1
{
UserFk=User1

```
        CountResults=2 (the two hashtags of this user exists in the hashtag repository)

        HashtagsFk=List<Hashtag>{hashtag1, hashtag2}; // (swimming and running}
    }
```

Result1
{
UserFk=User2

```
        CountResults=1 (only the hashtag swimming existsin the hashtag repository)

        HashtagsFk=List<Hashtag>{hashtag1}; // (swimming)
    }
```

I don't see how to do it by linq.

Comment: Why do you have to use LINQ? Are you saying you have a non-LINQ working version?

Comment: No I did not but through foreach I could do it. I think linq should be more performant. And would be simpler in the code.

Comment: LINQ may be shorter, but there's a high chance it will be less performant than more. It hugely depends on how it's done (like anything), but LINQ is a hammer, and not every problem is a nail. With loops/dictionaries you generate yourself you can see exactly what is done and where. With LINQ you might end up making extra steps just to make it work, and exactly how LINQ methods are implemented isn't obvious so if you wanted to be sure of how a LINQ version does something you'd need to know exactly how LINQ does what it does for each operation

Comment: Could you give a sample input and output? Maybe share your working foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is an answer to my issue.

```
  var userCommon = _userRepository.GetAll().Include(h => h.HashtagUsers).ThenInclude(h => h.HashtagFk)
                 .Where(s => hashes.Intersect(s.HashtagUsers.Select(h => h.HashtagFk.Code).AsEnumerable()).Count() > 0);

            userCommon.ForEach(res =>
            {
                var result = new HashtagResultSearchDto();
                result.UserFk = ObjectMapper.Map<UserDto>(res);

                var d = res.HashtagUsers.AsQueryable().Select(h => h.HashtagFk);

                result.CountResult = result.Hashtags.Count();
                result.UserId = res.Id;

                hashtagResultSearchDtos.Add(result);
            });
```